# How to derive from C++ std::basic_ostream and make the << operator virtual?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, std

I am writing a class that has various messages output. I want to make this class general and platform independent, so I am thinking of passing a **basic_ostream** reference to it and it can dump all the messages into the stream. By doing this, if the class is used in a console program, I can pass **std::cout** to it and display in console window.

Or I could pass a derived ostream to it and redirect the message to some UI components, e.g. ListBox? The only problem is the data inserter `operator <<` is not a virtual function. If I pass the derived class reference to it, only the **basic_ostream** << operator will be called.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why not use the generic `std::ostream` interface and change the underlying `streambuf` based on your context? No virtual functions needed.

Comment: You cannot make a non-member function virtual.  `operator<<` is not not a member of `basic_ostream`, but a free function.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: But I need to pass the base class std::ostream reference to my class. In such case,  my derived class from ostream's << operator will never be called.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: Yes that is right. So I'd like to have some workaround.

Comment: There's no such thing as `basic_ostream << operator`. There is about eleventy zillion different standalone (non-member) functions and function templates named `operator <<` that accept `std::ostream&` as the first argument.

Comment: A workaround has already been suggested. Devise your own class derived from `std::streambuf`. That's how things are done. `[io]stream` does formatting, `streambuf` does IO. You need to do IO, therefore...

Comment: @n.m. This also confused me. I found something like this in ostream.  _Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(unsigned int __w64 _Val), this is the operator << that only takes one arg. I though it was in the class basic_ostream definition, so it will be the member operator of class basic_ostream. But it is actually outside it, it is a standalone function. Then which stream is it trying to insert to?

Comment: I'd add one more detail: it's not so much that ostream does formatting and streambuf does I/O. Rather, most of the formatting is handled by a locale associated with a stream, and in individual overloads of `operator<<`, while streambuf handles the I/O. The ostream itself, therefore, is mostly a "matchmaker", putting together a locale to handle formatting with a streambuf to handle the I/O.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will look into implementing a derived streambuf.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. There may be `operator<<` functions which are members of `std::ostream`. Not all such functions will be members though. Anyway, these functions cannot and should not be overridden.

Comment: @NanZhang - you should post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

*Nan Zhang's own answer, originally posted as part of the question:*

Follow up: OK, here is the derived std::streambuf that implements required functionality:

```
class listboxstreambuf : public std::streambuf { 
public:
    explicit listboxstreambuf(CHScrollListBox &box, std::size_t buff_sz = 256) :
            Scrollbox_(box), buffer_(buff_sz+1) {
        char *base = &buffer_.front();
        //set putbase pointer and endput pointer
        setp(base, base + buff_sz); 
    }

protected:
    bool Output2ListBox() {
        std::ptrdiff_t n = pptr() - pbase();
        std::string temp;
        temp.assign(pbase(), n);
        pbump(-n);
        int i = Scrollbox_.AddString(temp.c_str());
        Scrollbox_.SetTopIndex(i);
        return true;
    }

private:
    int sync() {
        return Output2ListBox()? 0:-1;
    }

    //copying not allowed.
    listboxstreambuf(const listboxstreambuf &);
    listboxstreambuf &operator=(const listboxstreambuf &);

    CHScrollListBox &Scrollbox_;
    std::vector<char> buffer_;
};
```

To use this class just create a std::ostream and initialize with this buffer

```
std::ostream os(new listboxstreambuf(some_list_box_object));
```