# "Overriding" ostream& operator <<

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I would like to implement a stringstream object which represents a stringstream of a certain *type*.

For instance,

```
class ohtmlstringstream : public std::ostringstream {
};
ohtmlstringstream& operator <<(ohtmlstringstream& ohss, double d) {
    ohss << "<div title='double'>" << d << "</div>";
    return ohss;
}
```

Sadly this does not work, and any `ohtmlstringstream` object I create which I `<<` a double into just runs `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, double)`.

What's the way to do this? Looks like I should not be inheriting ostringstream.

I really just want a clean and simple way to "fork" the ways that a particular type can be serialized. For a long time I had only ever wanted to serialize a type in a single way, but now I want to build string representations of my types for at least 3 cases: In a HTML (or XML) representation, in JSON, and in the way that I already do which is something basic for dumping into the terminal while debugging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not allowed to inherit from standard classes except the exception ones.

Comment: @user2345215 Yeah, so what do I do? Should I do some [stringbuf inheriting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10301764/340947)? Or could I perhaps make my class contain its own stringstream?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Nh97lA). The problem must lie in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But this does not: http://ideone.com/iXnRmM The problem is that it doesn't work like I would expect

Comment: Of course. This does `operator<<(operator<<(ostream, const char*), double)`. The inner call returns `ostream&`, not `ohtmlstringstream&`

Comment: Ah, so I need to define the whole suite of `operator <<`s in whatever chain I'd be making. any point it gets broken, the rest default to the ostream one. Crap.

Comment: @user2345215: there are only a few classes which you are not allowed to derive from (actually, I think the `std::valarray<...>` classes are the only ones). There are also other classes than the exceptions explicitly intended as base classes (e.g. the facets and `std::basic_streambuf<...>`). The stream classes normally derived from but only for convenient initialization with a custom stream buffer.

Comment: I suppose you could implement a custom `num_put` locale facet and imbue it into the regular `stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the general wisdom of deriving from `std::ostringstream`, perhaps a global

```
template<typename T> 
ohtmlstringstream & operator <<(ohtmlstringstream& ohss, T const & t)
```

in the following vein would do for you:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class ohtmlstringstream : public ostringstream {};

template<typename T>
ohtmlstringstream & operator <<(ohtmlstringstream& ohss, T const & t)
{
    static_cast<ostringstream &>(ohss) 
        << "<div title='"
        << typeid(T).name() // For the sake of illustration
        << "'>"
        << t << 
        "</div>\n";
    return ohss;
}

// Testing ...
int main()
{
    ohtmlstringstream ohtml;
    ohtml << string("Testing") 
        << '1' << 2 << 3.0f << "4" << endl << "Bye" << endl;
    cout << ohtml.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<div title='Ss'>Testing</div>
<div title='c'>1</div>
<div title='i'>2</div>
<div title='f'>3</div>
<div title='A2_c'>4</div>

Bye
```

`typeid(T).name()` is doubtless not a satisfactory descriptor of `T`. You
might replace it with custom of specializations of, say:

```
template<typename T>
std::string type_desc(T const &)
{
    return typeid(T).name();
}
```

for all `T` you require (resigning yourself to this much drudgery).

Note that inserting a manipulator (e.g. `std::endl`) terminates the "html-ization",
because the insertion returns a reference to the base `std::ostream`.

If you don't want this to happen, you would probably want the manipulator
merely to be noted, but not acted upon, in the html output. So you might
add the specialization:

```
inline ohtmlstringstream & 
operator <<(ohtmlstringstream& ohss, ostream & (*pf)(ostream &))
{
    static_cast<ostringstream &>(ohss) 
        << "<div title='"
        << typeid(pf).name()
        << "'>"
        "</div>\n";
    return ohss;
}
```

With this addition the output becomes:

```
<div title='Ss'>Testing</div>
<div title='c'>1</div>
<div title='i'>2</div>
<div title='f'>3</div>
<div title='A2_c'>4</div>
<div title='PFRSoS_E'></div>
<div title='A4_c'>Bye</div>
<div title='PFRSoS_E'></div>
```

(Built with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.3)

Comment: aha! The use of `static_cast` inside a templated `operator<<` for the `ohtmlstringstream` is clever, I wonder how long it would have taken me to come up with it.

Comment: Just to leave some more breadcrumbs ... I didn't actually end up implementing this using inheritance, as suggested: I figured I might want to track more state in my html serializer object. However this is still a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the numeric types, you *could* use a custom `std::num_put<...>` facet to format the values. However, other types generally do not let you intercept the processing.

Comment: Yeah, no, I'm definitely interested in doing this on all types in general.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up though, Igor mentioned this too. It prompted me to hunt around in `gcc -E` output and I found that the basic types' `operator <<` template implementations are full of error checking and applying `num_put` and other things that seem vaguely unnecessary. Looks like I'll be able to write some of my own templates to build a much faster "stringstream", and in fact I may well have to implement them to get a customized streaming class like `ohtmlstringstream` at all